# What does "path ends in a directory separator" mean and how to work around it?

Tags: mercurial

I just ran `hg pull` and it pulled two changesets from the central repository. Then I ran `hg update`, and it gave me this error:

> abort: path ends in directory separator: \

I've never encountered this error before. What does it mean? How do I fix the error?

Comment: This almost seems like a bug in Windows HG. You might consider filing it with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears there is a file called "\" in one of the latest change sets, and that's why I'm getting this error. On Macintosh computers, a file named "\" is permissible; but on my version of Windows it is not.

The solution is simply to delete the "\" file as it is unnecessary and will prevent Windows users from updating.

Comment: There are similar difficulties when you add files with identical names but different case on a case-sensitive filesystem - and then clone the repo to a filesystem which doesn't support case (e.g. on linux adding 'file' and 'FILE', and then cloning to windoze).